# how a proxy server can be local?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, localhost

i have a server and i setup vpn server on it,
in our country some websites are blocked.
but with this proxy server users can not surf websites because the websites URL are still blocked and they see block page ,

programs like Freegate , Gpass , how can make it for us to surf websites ? it means what happens after connecting to server so we set 127.0.0.1 in our browser as proxy server and why localhost is proxyserver in users computer .
i want to know this way to write a program like it .

regards , bye

Comment: "i want to know this way to write a program like it" suggests that stackoverflow is the right site.

Answer (score 3):

For the proxy server to work, and not be blocked, you would need the proxy server to be outside of your country and therefore outside of your government's ability to control.

Normally it looks like this:

```
 [ You ] -------> [ ISP (Controlled by Government) ] --------> [ Internet ]
```

You try to connect to a site on the internet and the ISP blocks it.

You want this:

```
 [ You ] ----> [ ISP (Controlled by Government) ] ---> [ Proxy ] ----> [Internet]
```

That way, the government doesn't block the access to the proxy, and the proxy returns the blocked content.

Comment: AS Tom said, as long as you have no control over the data BEFORE it comes into your country, it will still be blocked.